# How let Ubuntu share specific interface over Wire?

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, vpn

I shared my internet over Wire with others devices by *Clicking on the network icon > Edit connections > Share to other computer* . However, The problem is when I share my VPN connection and that VPN connection drops down/failed for any reasons; Ubuntu keeps shearing my internet which is wireless connection with others!

How do I let Ubuntu stick with vpn interface, once is dropped, the other devices get no internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found it:

1. Don't share your internet, instead of that set the Wired connection getting manual IP.
2. Give Wired connection local IPs such as "10.42.0.1/255.255.255.0"
3. Apply these iptables rules in Terminal:

   sudo apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)

   sudo bash -c 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

   sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT

   sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED \

   -j ACCEPT

   sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
4. At other device side, set manual iPs as well such as "10.42.0.15/255.255.255.0/10.42.0.1"

Done.
Once **eth1** (or whatever your target interface) get disconnected, all others devices get no internet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking about one way to do what you desired  using Network-Manager by having 2 profiles for your wired connection:

1. Profile wire_shared
2. Profile wire_not_shared

And then run some trigger that switches your connection between the two profiles depending on the VPN state. You can use cron job and simple script like [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Checking_if_networking_is_up_inside_a_cron_job_or_script)

But more detailed answer need more detailed input from your side:).

Comment: Great idea, but still it is possible to others devices get connected with wireless even for seconds :)

Comment: Depends on your VPN... is it OpenVPN, PPTP or ? You can start it outside of Network manager via command and add some pre-up post-down triggers... But clear solution using only Network manager won't work. It is just a simple unified Interface with nice GUI to time more sophisticated protocols...