# Help understanding iptables command

Tags: networking, iptables, ip-forward

What does every part of this command mean?

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: It means you should read `man sudo` and `man iptables`

Comment: Why so many downvotes?!

Comment: Don't know! looks like people are not in good mode at this morning lol

Comment: This is a very basic question with the answer very easily in reach.  He could have simply googled a couple commands for his answer and then asked a valid question if he didn't understand something.  The answers are snippets from man pages.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/468629/how-do-i-view-the-man-pages

Comment: @bc2946088 or indeed she, or otherwise... and personally, I find man pages pretty hard to understand and sometimes I need some interpretation and examples.

Comment: I agree, @Zanna.  They did select the answer that is a compilation of man page snippets though, hmm.

Comment: Yeah, I prefer the other one @bc2946088 :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the manual pages of [`iptables(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/iptables.8.html):

`iptables`:

> Iptables and ip6tables are used to set up, maintain,  and  inspect  the tables  of IPv4 and IPv6 packet filter rules in the Linux kernel. Several different tables may be defined.  Each table contains a number  of built-in chains and may also contain user-defined chains.

`-t nat`:

> Iptables and ip6tables are used to set up, maintain,  and  inspect  the tables  of IPv4 and IPv6 packet filter rules in the Linux kernel.  Several different tables may be defined.  Each table contains a number  of built-in chains and may also contain user-defined chains.
>
> This table is consulted when a packet  that  creates  a  new connection  is encountered.  It consists of three built-ins: PREROUTING (for altering packets as soon as they  come  in), OUTPUT  (for altering locally-generated packets before routing), and POSTROUTING (for  altering  packets  as  they  are about  to go out).  IPv6 NAT support is available since kernel 3.7.

`-A POSTROUTING`:

> Append one or more rules to the end of the selected chain.  When the source and/or destination names resolve  to  more  than  one address, a rule will be added for each possible address combination.

`-o eth0`: (eth0 is:)

> Name of an interface via which a packet is going to be sent (for packets entering the FORWARD, OUTPUT  and  POSTROUTING  chains). When  the  "!"  argument  is used before the interface name, the sense is inverted.  If the interface name ends in  a  "+",  then any  interface  which begins with this name will match.  If this option is omitted, any interface name will match.

`-j MASQUERADE`:

> This specifies the target of the rule; i.e., what to do  if  the packet  matches  it.   The  target  can  be a user-defined chain (other than the one this rule is in), one of the special builtin targets  which  decide the fate of the packet immediately, or an extension (see EXTENSIONS below).  If this option is omitted  in a rule (and -g is not used), then matching the rule will have no effect on the packet's fate, but the counters on the  rule  will be incremented.

Comment: I did, I even did fix this problem using iptable by myself: https://askubuntu.com/questions/845309/how-let-ubuntu-share-specific-interface-over-wire , but this one is very confused. Thank you any way

Answer (score 5):

`sudo`: It stands for “super user do!” as a Linux system administrator or power user, it’s one of the most important commands.

`iptables`: Is  used  to  set  up, maintain, and inspect the tables of IP  packet filter rules in the Linux kernel.

`-t`: This  option  specifies the packet matching table which the command should operate on.

`nat`: This  table  is  consulted  when a packet that creates a new connection is encountered.

`-A`:  Append one or more rules to the end of the selected chain.

`POSTROUTING`: One of three  built-ins of nat, for  altering  packets as they are about to go out.

`-o eth0`: Name of an interface via which a packet is going to be sent.

`-j MASQUERADE` : This specifies the target of the rule; i.e., what to do  if  the packet  matches  it.